# Solution to the equations $\prod_{n=1}^N x_n^{\nu_n} = 1, \sum_{n=1}^N x_n =1, \mathbb{R} \ni x_n \ge 0, \nu_n \in \mathbb{Z},$ unique?

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations

Given an $N$-tuple of integers $\nu_i$, is the solution (if one exists) to the equations $\prod_{n=1}^N x_n^{\nu_n} = 1$, $\sum_{n=1}^N x_n =1$, $x_n \ge 0,$ unique?

The solution $x'_n$ yields the mole fractions for each species $X_n$ in the chemical reaction $\sum_{n=1}^N \nu_n X_n = 0$ where the derivative of the system's Gibbs energy $G$ with respect to the number of moles reacted equals the standard Gibbs energy $\Delta G^o$ characterizing the reaction. I am curious if there is a unique set of mole fractions where this occurs. In the spirit of the motivating problem, we might also want to restrict to cases where:

- there is at least one positive $\nu_n$ and one negative $\nu_n$, and also require
- $\nu_n \neq 0$,

though I am also curious about the case of arbitrary $\nu_n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: If the $v_i$ are all positive, there is no solution. Same with all negative.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews oh yes good point. But are there ever multiple solutions?

Comment: No idea. If I could answer the question, I might have answered the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is not necessarily unique in general, which is not too surprising for a system of two equations with $N$ unknowns.

If $\;\exists\, i,j\;$ such that $\,\nu_i=\nu_j\,$ and $x_i \ne x_j$ are a solution, then $\,x_j,x_i\,$ are also a solution by symmetry.

Even if all $\,\nu_i\,$ are distinct, uniqueness is not guaranteed. Take for example $\nu_1=2$, $\nu_2=1$, $\nu_3=-1$, then the equations are:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{align}
\frac{x_1^2 \,x_2}{x_3} &= 1
\\ x_1+x_2+x_3 &= 1
\end{align}
\end{cases}
$$

Substituting $\,x_3=x_1^2\,x_2\,$ from the first equation into the second gives $x_1+x_2+x_1^2\,x_2=1$, so the family of solutions is the infinite set of triples:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{align}
x_1 &\in [0,1]
\\ x_2 &= \frac{1-x_1}{1+x_1^2}
\\ x_3 &= x_1^2\,x_2
\end{align}
\end{cases}
$$